# Displaying CartoDB visualization on mobile with "Where Am I" button

Tags: carto, mobile, phonegap

I want to display a CartoDb visualization on my mobile device, but also have an icon that shows where the device is and centers/zooms to it when I press it.  I'm trying to find nearby features.

If this isn't available via a web page, then perhaps via a PhoneGap plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the coordinates from the GPS data of the mobile phone, you can use the function setView of the map to center and zoom the map in that location.

Example: `map.setView([-41.393, 177.473], 8, { animate: true, duration: 0.25, easeLinearity: 0.25 });`